# Run program based on the response of message box in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a program which checks for negative values in the data and then pops up a message that the data contains negative values "do you want to continue or not?" Based on the message box response the program should run further. I want to stop the program if user press **No** and want to continue in pressed **Yes**.
How to do this?

Example code:

```
a  <-  any(data$time < 0)

if (a == FALSE)
{
    require(tcltk)

    msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "Negative Values",
        message = "Data have negative values,do you want to proceed further  \n Press YES to proceed according to the program and press NO to stop" , icon = "info", type = "yesno")
}
```

[Also See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WXEK.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

What about `readline` instead of a pop-up box?

```
f <- function(x) {
  ok <- if (any(x < 0))
    readline('x contains negative values, continue? ') else 'yes'
  if (tolower(substring(ok, 1, 1)) != 'y')
    return(x)
  min(x)
}


f(1:5)
# [1] 1

f(-1:5)
# x contains negative values, continue? YES PLS
# [1] -1

f(-1:5)
# x contains negative values, continue? NO THNK U
# [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

You can also use `utils::menu` for a similar function

```
f <- function(x) {
  ok <- if (any(x < 0))
    menu(c('Yes','No'), FALSE, 'x contains negative values, continue?') else 1
  if (ok == 2)
    return(x)
  min(x)
}

f(1:5)
# [1] 1

f(-1:5)
# x contains negative values, continue? 
# 
# 1: Yes
# 2: No
# 
# Selection: 1
# [1] -1

f(-1:5)
# x contains negative values, continue? 
# 
# 1: Yes
# 2: No
# 
# Selection: 2
# [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

`msgBox` can be converted to a character, then you can work on the result as stated below. Feel free to insert any code instead of `print()`.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html

```
require(tcltk)

data <- data.frame (
  "time" = c(1,2,3)
)

a  <-  any(data$time < 0)

if (a == FALSE)
{
  msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "Negative Values",
                          message = "Data have negative values,do you want to proceed further  \n Press YES to proceed according to the program and press NO to stop" , icon = "info", type = "yesno")
  msgBoxCharacter <- as.character(msgBox)
  if(msgBoxCharacter == "yes"){
    print("flow continues! enter commands here!")
  } else {
    print("flow stops! enter commands here!")
    # for example
    stop("the user pressed no!")
  }

  }
```

This is even simpler:

```
msgBoxCharacter <- as.character(msgBox)
  if(msgBoxCharacter == "no"){
    print("flow stops! enter commands here!")
    # for example
    stop("the user pressed no!")
  }
print("flow continues! enter commands here!")
```

Comment: how to do if i want to check less then zero values for other two more columns simultaneously..fer example for column **name** , **zone** , **city**

Comment: you should read some more basic R material, but: `with(data,any(name<0) || any(zone<0) || any(city<0))` (but those variable names don't sound like they refer to numeric columns, so it might not make sense to check them for negative values ... ?)